# Sistema de archivos de sólo lectura en linux - ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permisos

tengo un problema, instalé windows y linux en mi pc pero en linux no puedo usar la partición de D que es donde tengo todos los datos guardados.

Monté la partición siguiendo este tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNAJInots60&t=809s
(No funcionó)

La desmonté entrando en: sudo thunar le di click derecho a la partición y desmontar y luego montar de nuevo. (No funcionó)

También traté de dar todos los permisos ejecutando el siguiente comando: sudo chmod -R 777 datos
(No funcionó)

También traté de configurar la partición desde el sistema de discos de ubuntu y quedó como se ve en la imagen 2:
(No funcionó)

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
[![introducir el código aquí][2]][2]
```

[image: Imagen 2]

Comment: Hola. No estás preguntando en el sitio correcto. Porque no se trata de un tema de programación. Debes ir a [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) o [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) y revisar las preguntas ya formuladas y respondidas. Seguro, alguien ya tuvo y resolvió un problema similar.

Comment: windows con su "fastboot" no termina de escribir los datos a disco y lo deja "sucio" desde el punto de vista de linux, para desbloquearlo presiona shift mientras clickas en apagar, o desactiva el "inicio rápido" en windows ( por el momento no he visto que se pueda elegir que discos o volúmenes excluir de ese comportamiento sin marcarlos como extraibles )

Answer (score 0):

La solución [está aquí](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=300078)

Tan simple como ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
sudo chown -Rc $USER:$USER $HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Hermano, yo encontré la solución en este vídeo, es la solución 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS1tingPFZg

1. identificar el disco

   `sudo fdisk -l`
2. iniciar reparación ntfs (sustituye x por el número del disco o partición)

   `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdaX`
3. Desmonta el disco o partición

   `sudo unmount /dev/sdaX`
4. Vuelve a montar el disco con permisos de lectura y escritura

   `sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdaX`